# Getting current node id in views

Tags: views, theming

I'm on drupal 8, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the current node id in an override of views-view-unformatted.html.twig.

I have a view filled with titles with added links and I want to add a class to the one the corresponds to the current node id.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the node id in an override of `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`.
Find below code

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set nid  = row.content['#row']._entity.nid.value %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the node id from each row in `_entity`:

```
{{ row._entity.id }}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @sea26.2 this answer is specific to the question (which template is used and how the View is configured). If you have a more complex use cases see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278890/how-to-access-raw-data-in-twig-template-using-views-table-format

Answer (score 1):

I did this in preprocess
In your .theme file :

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  foreach($variables['rows'] as $key => $row){
    if(is_object($row['content']['#node'])){
      $variables['rows'][$key]['nid'] = $row['content']['#node']->id();
    }  
  }
}
```

And then in your template file

```
{{ row.nid }}
```

Will output the NID.

Comment: This worked for me in Drupal 9.

Answer (score 0):

Added class "**active**", if node_id same.
[image]

In your .theme file :

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted__YOUR_NAME_VIEW__block_1(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  $node_id = $node->id();

  $view = $variables['view'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  $id_view = $view->storage->id();

  if ($id_view == 'YOUR_NAME_VIEW' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';

    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
      $view_node_id = $row['content']['#node']->id();

      if ($view_node_id == $node_id) {
        $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
      }

    }
  }

}
```

**There is one condition!!!**
You need add any class in 'Row class' in your view.

**FORMAT** - Settings - Row class(The class to provide on each row.)