# Get raw node id value in views template without errors

Tags: views, 9

I need to get the raw node id value in a views template, but the debug comments are interfering. Based on [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2672656) I am using the following:

```
{{ row.columns.nid |render|striptags|trim }}
```

Which actually works, but I am also getting errors in the dblog relating the render method:

```
User error: "0" is an invalid render array key 
User error: "wrapper_element" is an invalid render array key
User error: "attributes" is an invalid render array key
User error: "default_classes" is an invalid render array key
```

Is there a better way to access the raw nid in a views template?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is about a views table template, then this topic might help [How to access raw data in twig template using views table format](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278890/how-to-access-raw-data-in-twig-template-using-views-table-format).

Otherwise you could simply use

```
{{ row._entity.id }}
```